# Failed to write statements

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra-2.0, datastax

i'm using spark with cassandra and i want to write data into my cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable(
 user TEXT,
 date TIMESTAMP,
 event TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY((user ),date , event)
);
```

But i got this error :

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to KeySpace.MyTable.
    at    com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:145)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:120)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:100)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:99)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:151)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:99)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:120)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1214)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.aroundReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1375)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
15/04/28 17:57:47 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.2 in stage 1.0 (TID 43, dev2-cim.aid.fr): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
```

and this warnings in my Cassandra log File :

```
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2015-04-28 16:45:21,219 BatchStatement.java:243 - Batch of prepared statements for [*********] is of size 8158, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 3038
```

after making some searchs in the Internet, i've found this link who explain how he fixes the same problem : 
http://progexc.blogspot.fr/2015/03/write-batch-size-error-spark-cassandra.html

So, Now i've modified my spark algorithm to add :

```
conf.set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key", "None")
conf.set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows", "10")
conf.set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes", "2048")
```

this values remove the warning message i got in cassandra Logs, but i still have the same error : `Failed to write statements`.

In my spark log fail i found this error :

```
Failed to execute: 
    com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBatchStatement@67827d57
    com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Key may not be    empty
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:103)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:140)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:293)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:455)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:734)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.java:36)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at  org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
```

Comment: in the stack trace left by the failure, do you see a **cause** ?  The warning has probably nothing to do with it.

Comment: i just edited my post in order to show the stack trace. But i don't see the cause in my stack trace.

Comment: i found this cause in the log file of spark : InvalidQueryException: Key may not be empty

Comment: oh. That's more concrete and quite explicit: Some row in the batch has invalid data. Can you show the code?

Comment: Yes, thank you it was only my fault, i had 6 rows with a null/Blank user. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution in the comments above (by Amine CHERIFI and maasg).

The column corresponding to the primary key was not always filled with a proper value (in my case with an empty string "").

This triggered the ERROR

```
ERROR QueryExecutor: Failed to execute: \
com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBatchStatement@26ad2668 \
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Key may not be empty
```

The solution was to provide a default non-empty string.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running in yarn-cluster mode, don't forget to check entire log on yarn using `yarn logs -applicationId <appId> --appOwner <appOwner>`.
This gave me more reasons for failure than the logs on yarn webUI

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:50)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:37)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:266)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:246)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
... 11 more
```

Solution is to set the `spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level=ANY` in your spark-defaults.conf

Comment: What should be the ideal spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.buffer.size ? how to calculate it ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by restarting my cluster as will as nodes.
Following is the things I tried.
I am also facing same issue I tried all the options above you mentioned in the blog but not success. 
My data size is 174gb. Total 174 Gb data , My cluster having 3 node, each node having 16 cores and 48 gb ram.
I tried to lode 174gb in a single shot at that time i have the same issue.
After that I segregated 174 gb in 109 file each 1.6 Gb and tried to lode, this time I faced the same problem again after loading 100 files(each 1.6 gb). 
I thought may be the problem with data in 101 file. I tried to load the first file and tried to lode the first file into the new table, and tried to lode new data into new table but all this cases having the issue.
Then I think it is the problem with cassandra cluster  and restarted the cluster and nodes also.
Then the issue gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Add a breakpoint in "com/datastax/spark/connector/writer/AsyncExecutor.scala:45 ", you can get the real exception.

In my case, replication_factor of my keyspace is 2, but I have only one alive.